# How do I handle events with interfaces in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, interface

I'm new to interfaces and I'm trying to understand how they work.

I wrote the following code, which works properly except the click event which is not firing.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim WithEvents Button As IClass = New MyButton

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Button.Parent = Me
    End Sub

    Public Sub ClickEventHandler(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal E As EventArgs) Handles Button.Click
        MsgBox("Piwpiw !")
    End Sub
End Class

Public Interface IClass
    Event Click(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal E As EventArgs)
    Property Parent
End Interface

Public Class MyButton
    Inherits SimpleButton
    Implements IClass

    Public Event click1(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal E As System.EventArgs) Implements IClass.click

    Public Property Parent1 As Object Implements IClass.Parent
        Get
            Return MyBase.Parent
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Object)
            MyBase.Parent = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

What's wrong with that code?

(PS: This is just an example allowing me to understand how interfaces work and doesn't have any functional meaning.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a single method in the `MyButton` class to make this work.

You need this:

```
Private Sub MyButton_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
    RaiseEvent click1(sender, e)
End Sub
```

Essentially `SimpleButton` already has a click method. It's being raised when you click your derived `MyButton` class. But the `Click` event on `SimpleButton` isn't the same event as `Click` on the `IClass` interface. You implemented that as `click1`. So you just need to raise the `click1` method when the `Click` method is raised. Hence the above method.

Answer (score 1):

In your sample code, I don't see a line where the event is raised. In order to be able to handle an event in the event handler, you'd have a spot in your MyButton class that raises the event, i.e.:

```
Public Class MyButton
    Inherits SimpleButton
    Implements IClass

    Public Event click1(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal E As System.EventArgs) Implements IClass.click

    Public Property Parent1 As Object Implements IClass.Parent
        Get
            Return MyBase.Parent
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Object)
            MyBase.Parent = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub SimulateClick()
        RaiseEvent click1(Me, New System.EventArgs())
    End Sub

End Class
```

You use the [RaiseEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwd3bwed.aspx) statement to raise an event.
Above sample, of course, assumes that at some point in your code, you call SimulateClick instead of having a real mouse click (which would involve painting the button and reacting to several mouse events). Once the event is raised, your handler will be called. You could do this from your Form1_Load method:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Button.Parent = Me
    Button.SimulateClick()
End Sub
```

I have noticed that your `MyButton` class derives from a `SimpleButton` class. Instead of having the SimulateClick-method, you could also react to a click in the `SimpleButton` class and place the `RaiseEvent` statement there.

Comment: Well, that is my question : assuming a class that has its own events which fire according its own logic, how to assign an interface and catch these events through an interface ? The class MyButton, is indeed derived from the class SimpleButton. It's not meaningful but it's a simplified example. My real code is pretty much complex, that's why I tried to replicate it with this few lines.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

Replace MyButton class with:

```
Public Class MyButton
    Inherits SimpleButton
    Implements IClass

    Public Shadows Event click(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal E As System.EventArgs) Implements IClass.Click

    Public Property Parent1 As Object Implements IClass.Parent
        Get
            Return MyBase.Parent
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Object)
            MyBase.Parent = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub ClickEventHandler(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal E As EventArgs) Handles     MyBase.Click
        RaiseEvent click(Sender, E)
    End Sub
End Class
```